# HuggingFace hate detection model

Tags: nlp, text-classification, huggingface

I am trying to train and evaluate a hate detection model using the [HuggingFace Transformers library](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) and this [dataset](https://github.com/t-davidson/hate-speech-and-offensive-language/tree/master/data). Model performance is secondary, just trying to get it going. I have preprocessed the data and tokenised it as shown below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import RandomState
import re
import preprocessor as p
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

# Loading raw data
original_data = pd.read_csv('../data/data.csv')

# Make a random test and train split
rng = RandomState()
train = original_data.sample(frac=0.7, random_state=rng)
test = original_data.loc[~df.index.isin(train.index)]

# Preprocessing: remove special characters using RegEx
REPLACE_NO_SPACE = re.compile("(\.)|(\;)|(\:)|(\!)|(\')|(\?)|(\,)|(\")|(\|)|(\()|(\))|(\[)|(\])|(\%)|(\\\$)|(\>)|(\<)|(\{)|(\})")
REPLACE_WITH_SPACE = re.compile("(<br\s/><br\s/?)|(-)|(/)|(:).")

# Custum function to clean the datasets
def clean_tweets(df):
  tempArr = []
  for line in df:
    # send to tweet_processor
    tmpL = p.clean(line)
    # remove puctuation
    tmpL = REPLACE_NO_SPACE.sub("", tmpL.lower()) # convert all tweets to lower cases
    tmpL = REPLACE_WITH_SPACE.sub(" ", tmpL)
    tempArr.append(tmpL)
  return tempArr

# clean training data
train_tweet = clean_tweets(train["tweet"])
train_tweet = pd.DataFrame(train_tweet)
# append cleaned tweets to the testing data
train["clean_tweet"] = train_tweet

# clean the test data 
test_tweet = clean_tweets(test["tweet"])
test_tweet = pd.DataFrame(test_tweet)
# append cleaned tweets to the training data
test["clean_tweet"] = test_tweet

# Tokenisation so the inputs are ready for the model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
```

The above code generates a table for the test data as:
[image]

As I understand, the next part should be the model training part and extracting the % of hate tweets. Any suggestions on implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this article:
https://medium.com/geekculture/simple-chatbot-using-bert-and-pytorch-part-1-2735643e0baa

Model training with explanation is given